# Require files by name everywhere

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

this is my project structure:

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── www
│   ├── css
│   ├── js
│       ├── file.js
│       ├── folder
│           ├── file2.js
│           ├── file3.js        
│   ├── lib
│   ├── folder
│       ├── file4.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
├── webpack.config.js
```

I'd like to be able to do something like `require('file')`, `require('file2')`, `require('file3')`, `require('file4')` from any file in any folder of my project.

What configuration do I need to set in my `webpack.config.js`? Do I maybe need to use `alias`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alias` sounds about right, just add to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        file: '/path/to/file.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You can read all about it: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias